# how to insert object key into object value and turn it into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

what I have is like this

```
const employees = {
  "0813562121": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Allison"
  },
  "8753452122": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Aria"
  }
}
```

I need to make it into like this

```
 const employees = [
     {
        "city": "Melbourne",
        "name": "Allison",
        "_id": "0813562121"
      },
      {
        "city": "Melbourne",
        "name": "Aria",
        "_id": "8753452122"
      }
    ]
```

i was thinking of using index of `Object.keys(employees )` and `Object.values(employees )`, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `Object.values`, but I'd use [`Object.entries`](http://const%20result%20=%20Object.entries(employees).map((%5Bname,%20value%5D)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20value._id%20=%20name;%20%20%20%20%20return%20value;%20%7D);) since it gives you both the property name and its value. Then it's a `map`:

```
const result = Object.entries(employees).map(([name, value]) => ({...value, _id: name}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const employees = {
  "0813562121": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Allison"
  },
  "8753452122": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Aria"
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(employees).map(([name, value]) => ({...value, _id: name}));

console.log(result);
```

That uses:

- `Object.entries` to get an array of `[name, value]` pairs from the object.
- `map` to map the entries of that array into a different format
- A concise-form arrow function for the `map` callback (more in a moment).
- Destructuring in the `map` callback's parameter list to get the `name` and `value` in named parameters.
- Spread syntax inside an object literal to spread out the own, enumerable properties of the objects into a new object, adding the `_id` property

Alternatively, you could modify the object rather than creating a new one, so that non-enumerable, or non-own properties are retained:

```
const result = Object.entries(employees).map(([name, value]) => {
    value._id = name;
    return value;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const employees = {
  "0813562121": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Allison"
  },
  "8753452122": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Aria"
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(employees).map(([name, value]) => {
    value._id = name;
    return value;
});

console.log(result);
```

The key thing there is that the **same** objects are in both `employees` and `result`, whereas with the first one we make a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const employees = {
  "0813562121": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Allison"
  },
  "8753452122": {
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "name": "Aria"
  }
}

let jsonVariants =[];
Object.keys(employees).forEach(function(key) {
   let obj =employees[key];
   obj["_id"] =key;
   jsonVariants.push(obj); 
});

console.log(jsonVariants);
```

Comment: Code dumps aren't generally *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and why. Also, your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) (you need to declare `obj`), and generally if you're using `forEach` but always `push`ing to a new array, `map` is a more idiomatic option. But great to do a Stack Snippet! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for showing my mistakes.